# How to iterate drawblesin Android?

Tags: android, resources, iteration

In my app I have in hdpi-drawables folder rather big number of graphics file, which are need to be the icons in list activity. So in my **ArrayAdapter** I set the values to *setImageDrawable*

So, I need the way to iterate the all files, which are in my resources to get the namesand some another properties from their. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find drawable id by it's name with this method

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Seems to be it that what I need. Thanks.